# Boosting algorithms with keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, adaboost

Is there any way I can use boosting algorithms like adaboost with keras for ImageNet using CNN? Scikit learn has a number of such algorithms but it appears the inputs for these models are different in there. I have manually written a code for ensemble learning but algorithms like adaboost can improve the performance considerably.